# Very confusing sentence: "out back stacking wood"

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

I came across this:

"Thought my old man was out back stacking wood"

I actually don't know if a broader context is needed but to my it is a straight sentence and the reason this is confusing to is the "out back" part.

I don't know if it is:

1 - Thought my old man was out(outside) back(again) stacking wood

OR

2 - Thought my old man was out(outside) back(In yard) stacking wood

also it seems like out back has a meaning of its own

Comment: It's a fairly common feature of relaxed conversational English that we sometimes omit the verb ***subject*** from the initial position in an utterance. The most well-known example being the "imperative", as in ***Go away**!* (omitted subject ***You***). It also occurs with non-imperative ***Didn't expect that, did you**?* (again, implied subject ***You*** missing from initial position). In your examples, the implied but missing subject is obviously ***I*** (first person singular). With missing definite article *...out **the** back*.

Comment: You get it right. *Out* means *outside, not in the house*, *back* - *in the backyard, behind the house*... Another meaning would be possible if *back-stacking* were a thing :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, isn't the preposition "in" also needed? like "In the back" another point is: don't you think omitting things like that gives the reader the possibilit of second interpretations? like the one I gave back(again)?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree that the most likely interpretation of the sentence is 2, but it does depend on context, what has gone before. It's possible that "my old man" had been stacking wood, then had to stop to do something else and was now "back" =  "returned to" doing it.

Comment: The 'back again' sense doesn't really fit with _out_ preceding it. She might say "I thought he was back out there stacking wood".

Comment: @PeterJennings: If ***I*** wanted to convey that "resumed doing something" sense (through the word ***back***), I'd put *that* instance of the preposition before the "locational" one ***out***. It wouldn't bother me to repeat ***back*** again as an additional locational preposition, but I could certainly see the second instance as "optional": *I thought he was **back** out [back] stacking wood.*

Comment: *out back* is so common in (US?) English that Wiktionary lists it as an adverb:   "(US) Outside at the back., e.g., *My car is parked out back.*" (Saying *back out stacking wood* seems very unlikely to me.)

Answer (score 2):

"out back" is an idiom.  It means "(in) the area behind the house" i.e. "(in) the backyard."

> I'm out back!

> Take this out back.

> My car is parked out back.

Both British and American, but perhaps more common in American English.

You might notice, if you listen carefully. A difference in the pronunciation of "out back" from "outback" (which means the Australian bushlands)

Also the subject has been omitted. The implied subject is "I".

Comment: I don't think this is at all idiomatic in British English. We would recognise it, but only as an Americanism. We'd say something like "out in the back garden".